# What if my boarding pass name does not match perfectly with my id card?

Tags: air-travel, tickets

My surname is LO and my given name is Kei Cheung Arthur while my boarding pass name only shows that I am Arthur LO.  Will it affect my boarding?

Comment: `Kei Cheung Arthur` If that is on your id, be prepared to answer some questions. My middle name was spelled twice on my boarding pass and BA said, as long as my first and last name matches with my id , it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the airline and your port of departure; because these checks are done at the gate and at most airports, gate employees are contractors and not airline employees.

*Although one time a few years ago I remember while departing Newark the INS was checking boarding passes on the jetway, which was weird.*

I have had similar problems, because I have a compound first name; so it it doesn't fit on the boarding pass, sometimes they give it a SURNAME/FIRSTNAME MR. sometimes its FIRSTNA/MIDDLE MR.

I have never had issues with this to be honest.

You also mentioned *id card* - if this is not your primary travel document, then I would recommend carrying another form of identification; like a passport, driver's license or other government issued identification that has your full name in English (if it is issued in your country's native language and that isn't English), your picture, an issue and an expiry date, and its clear who is the issuing authority.

If you have these with you, I can't foresee any issues that would prevent you from boarding.

You should also carry your travel reservation because this would help if they don't let you board - because against this you can be printed another boarding pass.